# react-select "closeMenuOnSelect={false}" problems

Tags: html, reactjs, react-select

select 3.1.1 and im trying to add a basic isMulti check list and I don't want it to close after each chooses so I added the

> closeMenuOnSelect={false}

but it's not working on localhost:3000 every time. (only when I'm in the incognito mode it's working).
it's not working on regular google and on firefox. so I tried to deploy and also on phone its not working.
hope for help or a smart bypass with the isOpen function maybe. thanks.

```
<Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={animatedComponents}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    hideSelectedOptions={true}
    backspaceRemovesValue={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`blurInputOnSelect={false}` Thats the Magic line that should add.